# How to create a Ruby string within a CocoaPod PodSpec?

Tags: ios, ruby, cocoapods

There is a common trick to re-use a string within a pod spec:

```
  s.version = '0.0.2'
  s.source = { :git => ..., :tag => s.version }
```

By reusing the s.version string after it's assigned, I don't have to remember to change two fields when I update my `podspec`.

But, what I'd really like to do is tag my code with "v0.0.2", not "0.0.2". So I tried to just create a new string by prepending a 'v' to the version:

```
  s.source = { :git => ..., :tag => 'v' +  s.version }
```

However, that bombs the `pod` command.

I recall seeing a trick while searching for something else a while ago that showed how to inject Ruby code into a spec, but I cannot find it now, and even if I could not sure it addressed what I'm trying to do.

So, my question is, is this even possible, and if so, how do I accomplish it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are missing a `.to_s` call. I created a sample podspec to reproduce your issue. Indeed, the:

```
s.source = { :git => ..., :tag => 'v' +  s.version }
```

does not pass validation using `lint` and I got lots of errors. However, I added the `to_s` call and it worked for me and `lint` started fetching my `v1.0.0` tag.

```
s.source = { :git => ..., :tag => 'v' +  s.version.to_s }
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Great! I don't know Ruby at all. s.version is a string, but I have to turn it into a string to create a new string (see why I'm getting dizzy!). It appeared to me that a single quote and a double one were more or less the same in Ruby - if this isn't true can you add a comment? In any case this was NOT the solution I had seen before. Hah - just saw your abstract on your home page :-) - lol!

Answer (score 5):

First I wanted to provide an alternative answer. Instead of using Ruby string concatenation

```
'v' + s.version.to_s
```

you could also have used Ruby string interpolation, which is what most people would use in this situation

```
"v#{s.version}"
```

In Ruby `#{...}` is like `${...}` in shell scripts or Perl, the whole expression is replaced by the output of the code fragment (`...`), which can be a variable, a method call or any other piece of code. But this only works in in double quotes (again, just like in shell scripts or Perl).

Now regarding the comment that the OP @DavidH made in reply to the answer of @RaffAl:

> I don't know Ruby at all. s.version is a string, but I have to turn it into a string to create a new string (see why I'm getting dizzy!).

Ruby is an extremely dynamic language, where everything is an object and almost everything is implemented as a method, even most of the operators. E.g. `a = b + c` in fact calls the method `+` (yes, that is a valid method name in Ruby) on `b` with the parameter `c`, so it's in fact the same as `a = b.+(c)`.

When you write

```
s.version = '0.0.2'
```

it looks as if you are just assigning a value to a variable but what happens in fact is that a setter method is called, as this code is the same as:

```
s.version=('0.0.2')
```

And yes, the method is in fact named `version=` (certain operators are allowed in method names in Ruby). In Java the method would most likely be named `setVersion()`. Just because you pass a string to a setter doesn't mean that this string is also stored anywhere.

And when you call

```
x = s.version
```

you are in fact calling a getter method:

```
x = s.version()
```

In Java this method would be named `getVersion()`. And this getter doesn't return a string, it returns a `Version` object. So your initial code

```
'v' + s.version
```

In fact does this:

```
'v'.+(s.version)
```

But the problem is, the `+` method of the class `String` doesn't know how to append an object of class `Version` and that's why it fails.

All Ruby classes must inherit from another class and if they don't, they simply inherit from the class `Object` and this class defines a method `to_s()`, so any Ruby object knows `to_s` (parenthesis are always optional in Ruby, `puts("Hello World")` is the same as `puts "Hello World"`). If they don't override it, it prints the class name and an encoding of the object ID, but a lot of classes have overridden this method to return something more meaningful. The `Version` class returns the version as a string.

Okay, but why does string interpolation work then? Because unless the result of the expression in `#{...}` produces a string, Ruby will call `to_s` on that result to get one, that's why.